# Android Lollipop - Bypass lock screen for popup activity

Tags: android, android-activity, popup, android-5.0-lollipop, lockscreen

I have `Activity1` which is a list screen of items. Each item can be viewed in a separate `Activity2` which is displayed as a popup. `Activity1` can be launched from the background and displayed even when the screen is locked. `Activity1` may also choose to automatically display the contents of an item in the list screen by starting `Activity2`. We can bypass the lock screen because both activities have the `WindowManagerFlags.DismissKeyguard` enabled in the `OnCreate` method.

Before Android Lollipop everything worked as expected. But now the popup `Activity2` is not visible unless the device is manually unlocked. If I change `Activity2` to be a full screen `Activity` then everything seems to work (Except transitioning from one activity to another will briefly display the lock screen). Any ideas on how to fix this cleanly?

Also, I have only tried the Galaxy S6/S6 Edge devices which have this new Knox security feature on them.

**Edit** I have changed `Activity2` to be a `DialogFragment` instead of an `Activity`. This worked for me best because the suggested answer used code that is deprecated or obsolete depending on the target sdk. `Activity1` is using the following flags to bypass the lock screen when needed.

```
getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
```

Since `Activity2` is now just a `DialogFragment`, it uses the window flags of the parent `Activity1`. I also remove those flags on the *"android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF"* action so that the activity bypasses the lock screen only when launched as a notification and not every time the activity is at the top of the stack. Permissions mentioned in the answer are required.

Comment: I ended up having to use a DialogFragment instead for the popup activity. This caused a whole bunch of other issues and code restructuring, but at least those I could get around.

Comment: Hi, Can you post how did you make Activity1 to displayed on the lockscreen please?

Answer (score 4):

For sure this snippet should help You (works with Lollipop):

```
        PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "My Tag");
        wl.acquire();

        KeyguardManager keyguardManager = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
        keyguardLock = keyguardManager.newKeyguardLock("TAG");
        keyguardLock.disableKeyguard();
```

and when leaving Your activity (i.e. onStop(), onPause() and onDestroy()):

```
keyguardLock.reenableKeyguard();
```

Also, don't forget about permissions:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
```

Comment: make it rather `onPause()`

Comment: Yes, and even in `onDestroy()` just to be sure.

Comment: Have You tried it? I use it on my Lollipop and it works perfectly.

Comment: Yes: Android.App.KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock' is obsolete: 'This class is obsoleted in this android platform'. I would have to change the target version then it may possibly work. But the dialog fragment solution works as well. But you may have the points.

Comment: Hi, Can you post the entire code of this snippet please?

Comment: @EliranKuta Hi, it's all of required code. I don't use anything above that. Works as it is :)